# How do i set the location of the newly created csv file?

Tags: python, csv

I have just created a csv file with the codes below. But how do I set the location of the new file? For example I want it in created in the desktop.

```
csv = pd.DataFrame(all_feature_array, columns=feature_name)
csv['start_row_of_file'] = start_row_col
csv['timestamp'] = timestamp_col
csv['class'] = obj_class
csv.to_csv(folder[-14:] + '-' + obj_class + '.csv')
csv.head()
```

Comment: Put the complete path  ` "/Desktop/user/new.csv"`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to append the location of the file infront of the file name to save , you would do it as such

```
location = "C:/User/Desktop/"
filename = folder[-14:] + '-' + obj_class + '.csv'
csv.to_csv(location + filename)
```

Comment: no problem :) just accept the answer if it solved your problem